# Connecting to the Server

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, web-services, ios, nsurlconnection

I have never interfaced with a web server before, i know little bit of xml but don't know anything about http headers. I need to basically connect to a server and pass information (using Cocoa-touch) and this is the information that was provided:

```
Request headers: 
POST https://www.example.org/example 
Content-Type: text/xml 
Content-Length: 638 
Authorization: [[developer-key]]
```

and i was given this request body:

```
<LetterValues> 
<FullName><![CDATA[John Doe]]></FullName>  
</LetterValues>
```

The request body is more than just this, I removed a lot just to keep it simple.

So can someone point me to a tutorial or right direction about how I can pass in this information?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "pass information". What exactly are you trying to do or what exactly do you need help with? How to POST to some URL with a header field called Authorization set to some value? How to handle an HTTP response? How to parse XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)xmlParsingInBackground
{
NSString xmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your XML REquest"];
NSURL * serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:@"YOUR URL"]];
NSMutableURLRequest * serviceRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
[serviceRequest setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[serviceRequest setHTTPBody:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *responseData;
NSURLResponse * serviceResponse;
NSError * serviceError;
responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest returningResponse:&serviceResponse error:&serviceError];
NSString *resp=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if(responseData != NULL)
{       
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    //[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];       
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    if(success)
    { // DO SOMETHING HERE
            }

}
```

DO THE ABOVE THING, AND IMPLEMENT FOLLOWING:

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string  

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

THIS WILL HELP YOU. :)

**ADDITION:** Download code from following link that will tell you how to implement above methods [Sizmic XML](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html).